# Replacing slack app mentions with usernames in the slack message log in Dataweave

Tags: slack-api, dataweave, mule4

I'm parsing the slack message log from `conversations.history` and any app mentions come in as `<@XX12345>`. I'm trying to parse the `XX12345` part in a conversation and replace it with username and get rid of the `<` and `>`. For eg:

```
Hello <@UA12345> how are you?
I'm good <@UA67890>. How about you?
```

should become

```
Hello @lookup(UA12345) how are you? 
I'm good @lookup(UA67890). How about you?
```

How do I achieve this using replace and regex in DataWeave? The lookup function is used to get the user name from Slack API. This function also needs to be triggered inside Dataweave (not sure if this is even possible). End result would be something like this:

```
Hello @Adam how are you? 
I'm good @David. How about you?
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the username in `<@UA67890>` is alphanumeric, you can use the following expression to get the required result

```js
yourText replace /\<\@([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\>/ with "@$(getUsername($[1]))"
```

This matches the regex `\<\@([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\>` which captures alphanumeric value in between a `<@` and `>` in a group and then replace it with `@$(getUsername($[1]))`, i.e. `@getUsername(everything that was captured as in the above group)`

You can create the function `getUsername` to actually call the lookup function and call the required flow. So your DataWeave will look something like this.

```js
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
fun getUsername(userid) = lookup('get-user-name-flowname', userid) // Any other transformation that you may need for passing the required payload before calling loopup
var conversation = 
"Hello <@UA12345> how are you?
I'm good <@UA67890>. How about you?"
---
conversation replace /\<\@([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\>/ with "@$(getUsername($[1]))"
```

**Update:** As mentioned in comment, you also need a flow `get-user-name-flowname` that will either use slack's REST API or `<slack:get-usersprofileget>` which will accept this ID and will return the username of the user

Comment: thanks @Harshank this works but now i have another problem. It replaces the user id with lookup(userid) literally. it doesnt call the function as i was hoping. How do i solve for that?

Comment: Are you saying that there is a function that you have defined called "lookup" in dataweave? and you want to call that?

Comment: yes im trying to call the existing lookup function in dataweave to run a flow against the values im fetching. in this case, the user id will be input to the function to return a username from slack api

Comment: Ohh, I misunderstood the question, I thought the lookup is a function that will be resolved by slack itself, and you just want the string. Can you edit the question to make it more clear?

Comment: I have updated it to actually call the lookup function. Noticed that in the question the flowname part is missing while calling lookup. Updated the answer accordingly

Comment: I believe that what is missing is to mention that flow `get-user-id-flowname` should contain a `<slack:get-usersprofileget>` operation with `payload` containing the user. The operation returns the profile information including the display name.

Comment: @aled I have added that info now, thanks for point it

Comment: @aled can you post an example of using the ```<slack:get-usersprofileget>``` operation with ```payload``` inside a mule flow?

Comment: @adityaparkhe please raise a separate question for that because this was not the original problem, and also it increases the scope of the question by a LOT